# How to have fine-grained control over the keystrokes?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

The users of my application need to fill two `DataGrid` columns with numbers. The columns may be long and oftentimes the numbers typed are the same. I figured I would make the app friendlier by adding these two features:

(a) When the user presses **Enter** on the right column, focus should go to the left one (as a carriage return would do). That way, the movement among cells would be performed by pressing **Tab** and **Enter**. I need to selectively override the default movement (directly down).

(b) The user should have the option to press **Control-D**, causing the value in the current cell to be replicated all the way to the bottom row.

I guess issue number one would be: to which entity (DataGrid? cell? column(s)?) should the event handler be attached?

TIA.

Note: A large percentage of my posts may be summarized as "How can DataGrid be more like Excel?"

Comment: Issue `(a)` is purely a UI specific issue and can be handled in code behind. It is not related to data nor application logic. Issue `(b)` is completely related to `Data` and should be handled at the ViewModel or Data Model level.

Comment: @HighCore - `(b)` may also need to be handled in code behind, re: if the datagrid is sorted on the UI side, then the binded collection will not be in the same sort order in the VM/DM; if that occurs, then handling the values to be updated in the VM/DM may result in the wrong items being updated. What do you think?

Comment: @MetroSmurf I think in that case the OP should use a `CollectionView` on the VM, to handle sorting, filtering, etc.